# sql join with like operator

Tags: sql

Hi I have 2 tables in my sqltable in which my first table has id's like 111,112,113 etc. and second table has same column also have column id which contains values like 111|aa,112|ab,114|ad and i need to select all the ids from second table which contain part of id of first column like 2nd table contains 111 and 112  which also there in table1 as 111 and 112 how can i select those recods itried below query but didbt get result.

```
    select t1.id,t2.id from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 where t2.id like t2.id +'%'
    also tried.
    select t1.id,t2.id from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 on t2.id like t2.id +'%'
```

can someone please give me a hint how should i do this.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you re really using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `CONCAT` to add the `%` character:

```
SELECT t1.id,t2.id 
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id LIKE CONCAT(t1.id, '|%')
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7af6ee35e3903ac631fc05d47e59cf2b)

**Note:** Also make sure you are using the correct columns on the `ON` clause. In the above demo and query `t1.id` is the numeric column (contains `111`, `112` or `113`) and `t2.id` is the string column (contains `111|aa`, `112|ab` or `114|ad`).

To avoid unexpected behaviour on numbers greater than 999 you can add the pipe character `|` to the condition too.

Answer (score 3):

You could try  usingb a proper ON clause

```
select t1.id,t2.id 
from table1 t1 
left outer join table2 t2 ON  t1.id like concat(t2.id, '%')
```

or

```
select t1.id,t2.id 
from table1 t1 
left outer join table2 t2 ON  t2.id like concat(t1.id, '%')
```

for the join you should use the column from two table not from the same table